# mysql error on moved tikiwiki installation

Tags: mysql, php

while move my tikiwiki installation from one to another server i ran into this issue:

i moved my tikiwiki(12.2) installation from one server(Apache 2.2.26, PHP 5.3.16, MySQL 5.5.25a, Mac Server App 1.5/10.7.5) to a new server Apache 2.4.18, PHP 5.5.36, MySQL 5.6.34, Mac Server App 5.2/10.11.6).

At the new place get this error in the browser:

```
System error.
The following error message was returned:
Duplicate entry 'iup0iinu0mrbd22cu0bv9n5uoq0uteko' for key 'PRIMARY'
The query was:
INSERT INTO `tiki_sessions` (`sessionId`, `timestamp`, `user`, `tikihost`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
Values:

    iup0iinu0mrbd22cu0bv9n5uoq0utekoou8qqdpl8fd2ea521vrd2vt3s5tfhu807h0t6pefkh2gfr4ntcd7ftgbtpgge1av7gibdt3
    1530885844
    xxxx.xxx.my-domain.de

The built query was likely:
INSERT INTO `tiki_sessions` (`sessionId`, `timestamp`, `user`, `tikihost`) VALUES ('iup0iinu0mrbd22cu0bv9n5uoq0utekoou8qqdpl8fd2ea521vrd2vt3s5tfhu807h0t6pefkh2gfr4ntcd7ftgbtpgge1av7gibdt3', '1530885844', NULL, 'xxxx.xxx.my-domain.de')
```

I did the reinstallation as recommend here: https://doc.tiki.org/Move-Tiki-to-a-new-server
I also did this locally on my working pc and it works like a charm.

After investigating this a while, i’m believe it could be a matter of php configuration.
The database field ‘sessioonId’ is type varchar(32). And the sql insert command wants to put a much longer string in it.

Any ideas who figure out this issue?
Thanks in advance for hints;-)

Marcus

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the `varchar(32)` isn't of sufficient size for that sessionId.

```
ALTER TABLE tiki_sessions MODIFY sessionId VARBINARY(128) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY;
```

I've used VARBINARY here because the sessionId just a random string and not really a charset. Upgrading from 12.2 might be an alternative assuming they have fixed the size here.